# JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean class is not working in spring boot 3.0.5 version

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, wsdl2java

I am migrating spring boot project from 2.5.6 to 3.0.5. Also i have migrated java version from java 8 to 17. This project contains wsdl web services. After that following bean class is not working.

```
public JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean proxyClass() throws MalformedURLException {
  JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean ret = new JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean();
  ret.setWsdlDocumentUrl(new URL(crmDelegatorURL));
  ret.setServiceInterface(CRMDelegator.class);
  ret.setEndpointAddress(crmDelegatorURL);
  ret.setNamespaceUri("url");
  ret.setServiceName("testService");
  ret.setPortName("port");
  return ret;
```

}

following package is not containing spring framework.

`import org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean;`

what are the alternatives I can use for above bean class?